# Query with inner join on containstable with double quotes taking forever

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have this SQL query, which is taking forever:

```
SELECT c.InsuredOrganisationId, 'CLAIM'
FROM Claim c 
INNER JOIN containstable(claim,(uniqueClaimRef,lossDetails,claimRef, insuredName,claimTitle),'"*insured*"') mc ON mc.[key] = c.id
WHERE c.InsuredOrganisationId IS NOT NULL
```

1. If I replace `'"*insured*"'` with `'*insured*'`, it takes < 1s ( I get 108 rows)
2. If I remove the WHERE clause, it takes < 1s ( I get 861 rows)
3. If I remove the inner join (so just select from the containstable), it takes < 1s ( I get 861 rows )
4. If I perform the same query on a different DB, it takes < 1s

I can't believe it is just slow due to too many rows needing to be processed, as really there aren't that many rows involved, and surely removing the WHERE in (2) would not have helped if that was the case.

It's strange because it is the combination of all 4 things (the use of the double quotes, the WHERE, the inner join and that particular DB) that causes the problem... take just one of those elements away and the problem is solved.

Could there be a setting on that particular DB which is causing a problem for this query?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the statistics were out of date, and the execution plan was performing a nested loop join, meaning that it was hitting the FT index once for each row returned from the other side of the join. After updating the statistics, the plan used a hash join, meaning that it performed a single hit to the FT index, built a hastable from it and matched on that instead.